# Prove related to equal circles and segments

Tags: geometry

Two equal circles intersect in $P$ and $Q$. A straight line through $P$ meets the circles in $A$ and $B$. How do I prove that $QA=QB$ please provide figure also.

Comment: The angle PAQ must equal the angle PBQ because if you fix the chord length and the radius, then the angle is fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Since $P,A,B$ are collinear, $\widehat{QPA} = \widehat{QPB}$ or they are supplementary. Let $r$ be the radius of the circles. Then, by the *[Law of sines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_sines)*, $QA= 2 r \sin \widehat{QPA}$ and $QB= 2r \sin\widehat{QPB}$. This yields $QA=QB$.

Comment: please show $\widehat{QPA} = \widehat{QPB}$

Comment: $\widehat{QPA}$ is the angle formed by the rays $PQ$ and $PA$ and $\widehat{QPB}$ is the angle formed by the rays $PQ$ and $PB$. $P,A,B$ lie on the same line. If $P$ is not between $A$ and $B$, then $A$ lies on the ray $PB$ and so the rays $PA$ and $PB$ are exactly the same. If $P$ is between $A$ and $B$, then $PA$ and $PB$ form a line and so the two angles are supplementary.

Answer (score -1):

[image: GeomConstrn]

The circum-diameters $D$  of the circles are equal as given and by virtue of  Law of Sines we have:

$$ D = \frac {QA}{\sin \beta} = \frac {QB}{\sin (\pi-\beta)} =\frac {QB}{\sin \beta} \rightarrow QA=QB. $$